# How to pass key value in one params in Spring REST

Tags: java, spring

I want to pass key value pair in Spring REST params using this command:

```
curl http://localhost:11004/room/page?pageNum=1\&pageSize=1\&params={"key":"value"} -H "token:1"|jq '.'
```

but the server side received params parameter by string like this:

```
params="key:value"
```

How to make the server side get key value pair?This is the server side model code:

```
public class PageQuery<T> {
    private Integer pageNum;
    private Integer pageSize;

    private T params;
}
```

This is the server side function:

```
public Response<PageBean<Room>> queryRoomByPage(PageQuery<Map<String,String>> request);
```

How should I tweak my request or server side code to make it possible?

Comment: Are you doing this just for Pageable code or you'll pass another parameter as mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `pageNum=1\&pageSize=1\&params={"key":"value"}` every part splits by `&` then it leads to your `params="key:value"` because here `Map<String,String>` you said to Spring that there is should be string at key and value

Example to change method input:

```
@RequestParam("pageNum") Integer pageNum, @RequestParam("pageSize") Integer pageSize, @RequestParam("params") Map<String, String>
```

Do not use such a complicated HTTP query parameter as json, please use http body for this and await specific input JSON for which you have a specific description represented by java class

Better: do not use `String`, if your input can be represented as a specific business object, especially at Map. Neither HTTP client nor other engineers won't understand it, at least they "just know"